# Query SCD type 2 table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, data-warehouse, scd

Imagine the following table:

```
ID  Name    Type    Start_Date  End_Date
1   Cust_1  Retail  01/01/2010  21/07/2010
1   Cust_1  Oher    22/07/2010  17/05/2012
1   Cust_1  Corp    18/05/2012  31/12/9999
```

I would to know if there's any way to build a view that return the correct type, according to a date sent as parameter. For example:

`SELECT Type WHERE date_to_analyse = '21/06/2010'` should return 'Retail'
`SELECT Type WHERE date_to_analyse = '18/06/2012`' should return 'Corp'

Date_to_analyse is not a column of the table, I want to avoid using Stored Procedures.
My idea is making the query "clean", instead of using the following query

```
SELECT Type WHERE date_to_analyse >= Start_Date AND date_to_analyse < End_Date
```

Is this even possible?

Thanks

Comment: A clean query has nothing to do with it being efficient. But you can make it `cleaner` by using `between` clause. Something like `select * from table where date_to_analyse between start_date and end_date` . Also note the `between` clause is inclusive of both the values.

Comment: thank you, @Utsav. That's why I used `date_to_analyse >= Start_Date AND date_to_analyse < End_Date`. I am not working on performance at this moment, I'm just trying to implement some changes in current db without impacting too much the way the tables are being queried. Currently, there's no SCD in place, just the last state of the table

Comment: `>=` and `<` is not equal to `between`. If you want to include both `start_date` and `end_date` in the output, then only use `between` else stick with `>=` and `<`.